# Why is my conditional python code for dataframe changing values that do not meet the condition?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two columns in a pandas dataframe that I am interested in, namely `trade_type` and `execution_venue`. The name of the dataframe is `table_df`.

At the moment, the `execution_venue` for all `trade_type` is marked as`AQXE`.

I am adding the following conditional statement so that when we have a `DARK` `trade_type`, the `execution_venue` takes the value `ABCD`.

Here is my code to do this:

```
trades_df.loc[trades_df['trade_type'] == 'DARK', 'execution_venue'] = {'AQXE': 'ABCD'}.get('AQXE')
```

Now the issue I am having is that while the above works as intended for the `DARK` trades, it is changing the `execution_venue` of all the other `trade_type`s to `NAN`.

Any ideas why this could be?

When I remove the above code, the `execution_venue` for the other trades appear as normal.

Comment: Strange. Works fine for me. No NAN

Comment: Can you post a full reproducible example? With all imports? That would just be running